# How to call a Youtube Data API through HTTPUrlConnection in Android with using headers?

Tags: android, httprequest, httpurlconnection, youtube-data-api

I am trying to develop a part of my app in which i want to get video details for a keyword. I am using the search list API. I think I have an issue with the authorization. I am getting a 401. I have tried passing my authorization details.

I have tried the following code after going through a few resources online and I am current getting the java.io.FileNotFoundException at the line at which i get the Input Stream. The connection code that I am getting is a 401.

The given code is in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask.

```
String ytres="";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            Log.d("youtubedata","a1");
            url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=queen%20bohemian");
            Log.d("youtubedata","a2");
            Log.d("youtubedata","a");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Bearer MYAPIKEY");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Accept", "application/json");
            Log.d("youtubedatanum",Integer.toString(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
            ytres=ytres+current;
            System.out.print(current);
        }
        Log.d("youtubedata",ytres);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return ytres;
```

I do suspect the issue is in the way i have passed my API Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the API docs at [Calling the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#calling-the-api) and at [Search Endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

You'll see that your URL does not contain the needed API key passed on as the *key* parameter.

It may also worth it to dug up Google's own sample Java implementation at [Search.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/youtube/api-samples/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java). However, that code, due to the layer of library abstraction it uses, is not of immediate help since it obscures the way a client should work directly with the API.

Answer (score 0):

For **You-tube Data API** error 401

Possible issue for unauthorized (401) can be

- *authorizationRequired*
- *youtubeSignupRequired*

Check You-tube Data API error doc [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.RequestContextError).

Also confirm that you have follow [THIS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android) steps to integrate API.

Sample API Code you can find [Here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java)

Hope this can help you.